# Azure Active Directory B2B - Helping confused users login

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

We're using Azure AD B2B for a few bespoke applications (customer portals etc) with several hundred guest users from other directories, mostly non-tech staff from small businesses with outsourced IT. Generally it works great but we regularly receive queries from customers confused about similar things and would like to provide an FAQ.  I'm referring to issues like:

- unsure which login details to use, since they're unfamiliar with SSO and don't realise they can just use their own O365 / Microsoft accounts, which many already have
- surprised/suspicious when our application asks them for permission to access their account
- have set Outlook etc to remember their password, haven't had to use it in years and don't know what it is, and we can't reset it since the account is in *their own directory*

Not asking for help with the specific issues above, my question is about the best way to provide easy access to some kind of FAQ page **during** the AAD sign-in process. The issue is that once they start the process (which is the part they struggle with), they only get redirected back to the application upon successful auth, and Microsoft doesn't give much control over the UI.

A perfect solution would be to have an FAQ or help link on all the AAD sign-in pages, but I can't see any way to do this, even on our own company branded sign-in pages. The only relevant option is "Sign-in page text", which isn't really sufficient.

What's the best-practice way to help non-technical users with these kinds of problems? E.g. can we tell AAD to redirect to a help page after login failures?

Comment: Since Azure AD acts as a IDP and portal is from Microsoft we dont really have much control over AAD login except customizing the invite messages. One way(and probably only way) would be to publish an FAQ document as part of communication pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to specify custom error messages or error pages for Azure AD B2B. It is possible if you are using Azure B2C. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview

Also, for B2B users, they will receive an email if they are invited to your tenant. So they will know which account to use to login.

Comment: I'd really rather be able to provide help before the user causes an error to avoid that situation in the first place, but I guess B2C error messages are the best we can do. Thanks! And yeah I know they receive emails when invited. Some are still confused about this though, which is the reason we wanted to provide extra guidance during the sign-in process

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to customize messages using Language customization. You enable language customization in the tenant. You then download the default messages from the tenant. the file is in JSON format. You make your changes to the JSON file messages and then upload the file...

Most AD B2C pages have an "intro" with a class of intro. Below is an example of intro text provided by the API on sign up. You should be able to customize these messages to better help the user through the process.

```
<div class="intro">
    <p>Enter a number below that we can send a code via SMS or phone to authenticate you.</p>
</div>
```

Here are examples of the intro text for sign in that should be able to be customized in the JSON file:

```
<div class="social" aria-label="Sign in with your social account" role="form">
  <div class="intro">
    <h2>Sign in with your social account</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="localAccount" aria-label="Sign in with your user name" role="form">
    <div class="intro">
      <h2>
        Sign in with your user name
      </h2>
    </div>
```

[Instructions can be found here: Language Customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-language-customization)

A list of many default values and id's can be found here:
[Azure B2C default text and id's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids)

Comment: Hey, sorry I missed your answer a couple of months ago.  This is a cool idea and we can always use it as a fallback; although I think helping our customers get things right the first time (via better UX) is preferable to giving them more helpful error messages ;)